# Extract string between two keywords for all files in a directory

Tags: regex, xml, search

I have a bunch of .xml files in the following folder:
"C:\Users\Kavinda JD\Desktop\Manual\XMLs\Output"

I wish to search this entire folder for all the .png file references.
For example, one .xml file has the following:

```
        <li class="list1-item clearer">
            <div class="ie8fixer" />
            <p class="step2-list1-nonmark-heading">The following image is an example.</p>
            <div class="bigImage"><img src="../image/vl7ie02.png" alt="VL7IE02" class="figure-graphic--bigImage" />
            </div>
        </li>
```

I need something that will go through each .xml file and pick out the name of the .png file.
So for the above example, the ouput would be:

```
vl7ie02.png
```

I have already tried using Notepad++ to search for the string ".png", but for some .xml files, a single line contains a lot of information and the png file name occurs at the end of the tag. So Notepad++ doesn't display this in the output window - even though there is a match. I then have to go to the file and the relevant line and grab it from there.

I don't really want to do this since there are over 6000 xml files in the directory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following Regex:

```
img.*?src=".*(?<="|\/)(\w+\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif))"
```

The more detailed explanation is on [Regex101][2].

- Note that the image path is always in the `img` tag and `src` attribute.
- Also note that the `src` attribute content is always wrapped between the quotation marks `"`.
- `(?<="|\/)` is a positive look-behind which indicates that the image name and extension must be *after* a quotation character `"` or the frontslash `/` (must be escaped).
- `\w+\.` matches the filename with a dot. If you want ex. spaces in the filename, use `.+`.
- `(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)` are the possible extensions. If you don't care them, use `\w+` instead.
- Wrap the filename with the dot and the extension inside the capturing group brackets `(\w+\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif))`.

Comment: `\w+` is too restrictive for filename, i.e.`my file.png` or `img-1024 x 768.jpg`

Comment: @Toto: Thanks for a hint. The `\w+` might be changed to `.+`. I followed the OP's example. If he edits the question or asks for more info, I'd provide the less restrictive answer. Yet I can mention it in mine.

Comment: Brilliant! Works as expected! Thank you @Nikolas

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -Eo "[^/]+\.png" *.xml`

if you are using windows see [Grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)